# Maintaining State

Tags: android

When  I   rotate   my Screen from horizontal   to  vertical
All  the  text  I have entered is cleared.How    to mainTain the state.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [onSaveInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29).